# Angular js animate on $scope variable update on <p> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$interval(function() {
        var count = $scope.announcements.length;
        for(var i=0;i<count;i++) {
            if($scope.announcement == $scope.announcements[i].description) {
                if(i==count-1) {
                    $scope.announcement  = $scope.announcements[0].description;
                    if($scope.announcement.length >= 100) {
                        $scope.readmore     = true;
                        $scope.short_ann    = $scope.announcement.substr(0,85);
                    }
                    break;
                } else {
                    $scope.announcement  = $scope.announcements[i+1].description;
                    if($scope.announcement.length >= 100) {
                        $scope.readmore     = true;
                        $scope.short_ann    = $scope.announcement.substr(0,85);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
    }, 5000);
```

The $scope.announcement is updated at every 5 seconds and i want a small animation while changing the ng-bind of this

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2784-animating-a-single-item-using-ngrepeat-and-nganimate-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directive that watches for value changes on a property and performs the animation.

For example:

```
app.directive('flash', ['$animate',
  function($animate) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch(attrs.flash, function(newValue, oldValue) {

          if (newValue === oldValue) return;

          $animate.addClass(element, 'flash').then(function() {
            element.removeClass('flash');
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Usage:

```
<p flash="announcement" class="animated">{{announcement}}</p>
```

If you know you will use `ng-bind` instead an alternative usage is:

```
<p flash ng-bind="announcement" class="animated"></p>
```

With this second version you need to watch `attrs.ngBind` instead of `attrs.flash`:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngBind, ...
```

Note that this example uses `ngAnimate` and `animate.css` to perform the animation.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/R0dWpE0VSscqE4mJ6462?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for Your great help

Answer (score 0):

use ng-model to your p tag to show actual data, and ngAnimate or smth else...

```
<p ng-model="announcement">{{announcement}}</p>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate